# Obtain Default Content Access Account via PowerShell

Tags: 2010, development, powershell

As part of farm configuration audit, I need to obtain the current content access account. While I've found several resources for setting the default content access account for search using PowerShell, I haven't been able to find any resources on where the property exists in the object model for query purposes. In 2007 it appears to be a [property of the SPSearchService object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.search.administration.spsearchservice.crawlaccount%28v=office.12%29.aspx), does anyone know where it exists in 2010?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know that it can be accessed via `Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Content.DefaultGatheringAccount` property. The Content object needs `SearchServiceApplication` instance which you can get from powershell.

Here is powershell script:

```
$searchApp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication "Your Search Service Application Name"

$content = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Content -ArgumentList $searchApp

Write-Host $content.DefaultGatheringAccount
```

Hope that helps.